# jquery draggable how to keep x constraint and make the drag works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following script which use `.draggable`,
I need to make sure when user click and drag the text, text scroll horizontally within its parent constrain.

Currently I am using this code but does not work properly.
What is wrong? How to fix it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t1smb6u8/

```js
jQuery("#child").draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  axis: "x",
  containment: "parent"
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#child {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div id="child"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `containment: "parent"`

```js
jQuery("#child").draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  axis: "x",
  //containment: "parent"
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#child {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div id="child"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum </div>


</div>
```

Comment: It does not work as expect, object should be scrolled only within its size, when now user scroll the text, it can scroll so much that in the red box you see only white. I need to apply a constrain an limit the scroll. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Radex add constraint in 'start' of dragbble and return false if it far left or right

Comment: Could you please add a live example, so I can accept your answer. Thanks!